# MySQL: How to insert into the middle of JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json

Say I have JSON stored in MySQL as JSON type:

```
{"key1":"value1","key3":"value3","key2":"value2"}
```

and I want to insert "key4":"value4" at a specific position, e.g.:

```
{"key1":"value1",   "key4":"value4"   ,"key3":"value3","key2":"value2"}
```

Is there purely a MySQL command to do this?

JSON_INSERT looks to only be able to append to JSON.

I'd rather do it as a MySQL command to keep it efficient, otherwise, I would have to pull the entire JSON string out, decode it, do some PHP commands, and then restore it. Seems like there should be a MySQL way of saying put this in at index 2 or so.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: The order of elements in a JSON object is not significant. Why do you care where it puts it?

Comment: If you care about order, you should be using an array, not an object.

Comment: Take a look at the [JSON functions in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-array-insert).

Comment: You guys are making me think about how I set up my data structure. I think I can set up one of my data structures to be an array. Currently one almost is. I have it as `code`{key_name:[{k1:v1,k2:v2},{k1:v3,k2:v4}]}. `code` Don't think I need key_name so it would just be `code`[{k1:v1,k2:v2},{k1:v3,k2:v4}]. `code`. My other data structure, I would like to keep it as above but don't actually need to specify an order. So I guess the answer is to split the order stuff into a JSON array and the non-order stuff is ok in a JSON object. If one of you wants to submit this answer I'll vote for it. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use a JSON Array for sequence. Here's an example:

```
var a = [{key1: "va1"},{key1: "val2"}];
```

Then you will use splice() to push on a specific index inside the JSON Array. Splice() is a javascript function.

```
a.splice(1, 0, {key1: 'adipiscing'});
```

Try running my snippet below: (By the way I'm using AngularJs)

```html
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    {{text}}
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
            app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
       var a = [{key1: "jp"},{key1: "id"}]
              a.splice(1, 0, {key1: 'adipiscing'})
              $scope.text = a;
            });
    </script>
```

Comment: The OP is looking for a MySQL method, not JS.

Comment: Just thinking if this could help since he tagged PHP on his question.

Comment: Even so, JS isn't PHP either.

Comment: Okay sir. I will be deleting my answer. Thank you for your thoughts!

Answer (score 0):

as @Sloan pointed out you could use the JSON specific functions, or  you can use several SQL hacks to get this done.

**Method 1:**

You can update the filed like this. This appends the new value to the end of the field.

```
UPDATE tablename SET fieldname=INSERT(fieldname, length(fieldname), 0, ',"key4":"value4"') WHERE .....
```

In PHP it would look something like this. The drawbacks for this method is that the value gets appended and not inserted to specific location. Secondly, it can only be added to already existing data.

```
$indata = '"key4":"value4"';

$SQL = "UPDATE tablename SET fieldname=INSERT(fieldname, length(fieldname), 0, ',$indata') WHERE .....";
```

**Method 2:**

This query inserts the new item at the second spot (as your requirement) if there are multiple items, else will append it just like the previous query

```
UPDATE tablename SET fieldname=INSERT(fieldname,IF(LOCATE(',',fieldname)>0, LOCATE(',',fieldname) , length(fieldname)), 0, ',"key4":"value4"') WHERE ...;
```

In PHP

```
$indata = '"key4":"value4"';

$SQL = "UPDATE tablename SET fieldname=INSERT(fieldname,IF(LOCATE(',',fieldname)>0, LOCATE(',',fieldname) , length(fieldname)), 0, ',$indata') WHERE ...;";
```

**UPDATE**

```
// JSON Object
{"key1":"value1","key3":"value3","key2":"value2"}
// Object properties do not have order so you can only add new properties

// JSON Array (of objects)
[{"key1":"value1"},{"key3":"value3"},{"key2":"value2"}]
// With array you can have order. So you can use 'JSON_ARRAY_INSERT()'
// To Add to position 2
// eg: UPDATE tablename SET fieldname=JSON_ARRAY_INSERT(fieldname, '$[1]', '{"key4":"value4"}');
```

NB: I haven't tested this so you might need to have it tweaked.

Comment: Looks like this is considering the JSON as a string and searching through it looking for commas to find the place where you want to insert. If I understand the code correctly it inserts at the 2nd position because there are two LOCATE commands. Is that correct?

Comment: JSON is basically a formatted string and is stored as such in the DB. The first LOCATE is looking to see if there is a coma in the data, which means there is at least 2 entries in JSON string. In this case the second LOCATE passes the position of the first coma, which is used for the insert. If no coma  in the string then it expect there only to be one entry in the JSON string and the new entry is appended to the end of the string. If you want to insert the entry at any other position the query need to be substantially redesigned.

Comment: Can you do string searches even if the JSON is stored as type JSON instead of type text?

Comment: To be frank, I have't tested it. I do not have a version of MySql that I can test JSON data type. If this doesn't work for you can try CASTing the field to string, do the editing and then CAST it back to JSON. If you keep your data as JSON array instead of JSON Object then you can do what you want. I will update the original post with more details.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    {{text}}
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
            app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
       var a = [{key1: "jp"},{key1: "id"}]
              a.splice(1, 0, {key1: 'adipiscing'})
              $scope.text = a;
            });
    </script>
```